# Can I get internet on my laptop by connecting it to my TV via an Ethernet cable?

Tags: internet, ethernet, tv

Can I get internet on my laptop by connecting it to my TV via an Ethernet cable?

My TV is connected to a smart TV antenna via a coaxial cable like this item on Amazon: ”[HDTV Antenna, Indoor Digital TV Antenna 80 Miles Range with Newset Amplifier Signal Booster - 4K Local Channels Broadcast for All Types of Smart Television - Updated 2018 Version”](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BBQLDMV)

Would it be different if the TV was connected to a wall instead of the smart TV antenna?

Comment: What do you mean by “Smart TV?” Is that the name of a service, or are you talking about a brand of HDTV antenna that you are connecting to your TV? In general, if you are just receiving over the air HDTV there is no Internet connection associated with that.

Comment: Not this exactly, but this is what I'm referring to: https://www.amazon.com/Antenna-Indoor-Digital-Amplifier-Booster/dp/B07BBQLDMV

Comment: And yes it is over the air. If it was connected to a wall would that change anything?

Comment: If your TV isn't meant to use internet to display content, the chances for it to be able to share network are even smaller, assuming that your smartTV even shares internet data with your TV in the first place.

Comment: It can access the internet. Does that mean its possible?

Comment: @tracyo [I expand on my comment in my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1427529/167207), but an Internet connection is inherently two-way and receiving TV signal—HDTV or otherwise—is simply a one-way transmission. Can’t happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, you can’t.

### You cannot get an Internet connection—as you describe—from an HDTV antenna.

> Can I get internet on my laptop by connecting it to my TV via an Ethernet cable?

The device you are describing as “smart TV” is simply an HDTV antenna with a signal amplifier. All an HTDV over-the-air signal is is a digital signal a sent via analog method over the air. It is a one-way connection from a transmitter antenna to your receiving antenna. There is no inherent “Internet” available if you connected an Ethernet cable to the TV that is receiving that signal. And it technically could not happen as you describe since all Internet connections are two-way methods of communication whether you use it as such or not.

All the Ethernet cable on any HDTV is for is to allow the HTDV to be connected to your LAN; whether that be via a router or just a direct connection to a device.

Your HTDV has the *capability* to connect to the Internet via an Ethernet cable, but it doesn’t *provide* Internet connectivity via that Ethernet cable.

> Would it be different if the TV was connected to a wall instead of the smart TV antenna?

Not really. If you connected your HTDV to the wall, you would only get the “free” channels (if any) your local cable company would provide via coaxial cable.

To get Internet connectivity via the coaxial cable from the wall your cable company would need to provide that to you and that is typically not free. You have to pay a fee, and connect a cable modem to the coaxial cable coming from the wall.

If you want to use your TV with a cable modem like that, you would have to then connect the HTDV to the pass-through connection on the cable modem, or purchase a coaxial cable splitter for the wall connection to allow your wall connection to be shared by the cable modem and the TV itself.

Comment: @tracyo You’re welcome! If this answer was helpful, please be sure to upvote it. If it’s the answer that answered your question, please be sure to check it off as such.